# Microsoft bot framework v4 speech service

Tags: botframework, speech-to-text, azure-bot-service

I have developed Microsoft bot framework node js bot and connected to Facebook. When I am trying to add speech service to bot using facebook mic, am getting below error.

I have gone through the link [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/js/node) but getting below error when I am giving voice input through FB mic.

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open** 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\https:\cdn.fbsbx.com\'

below is the code snippet, function "**fs.createReadStream()**" generating error:

```
 async function openPushStream(filename) {
        // create the push stream we need for the speech sdk.
        console.log('---from  open push stream funcion ----',filename);
        var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

        // open the file and push it to the push stream.
        request(filename).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('userInputVoice.wav'))

        fs.createReadStream(filename).on('data', function(arrayBuffer) {
            pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.buffer);
        }).on('end', function() {
            pushStream.close();
        });

    var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
    // Setting the recognition language to English.
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
// Create the speech recognizer.
var recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
  function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    recognizer.close();
    recognizer = undefined;
    return result;
  },
  function (err) {
    console.trace("err - " + err);

    recognizer.close();
    recognizer = undefined;
  });
        return null;
    }
```

Please suggest, how to handle this issue. Thanks in advance.

I look forward for your response/suggestions.

Comment: Some code would be helpfull. Or an errorlog referring to the part of the code that fails.

Comment: @Hessel, I have kept the code snippet in my question . Please look into it and let me know you suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\https:\cdn.fbsbx.com\" does not make any sense. Any idea why filename resolved into that?

Comment: @Hessel, when I give the voice input through FB mic, we are receiving the input URL in " context._activity.channelData.message.attachments[0].payload.url" but when fs.createReadStream(filename) function appends "D:\home\site\wwwroot\" path to my input voice URL which leads to error "no such file or directory".

Comment: Tnx. Does not make any sense sorry. I would suggest to file a bug in the sample repo and fot the time being remove the prefix yourself in your code and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the path value that is read from the created stream by passing the `fd` property in as an option when you call `fs.createReadStream` (you can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)). Setting it to `0` tells the system not to pre-pend the stream path with the local pathway. Be aware that the `open` event will not be called when `fd` is passed in.

When tested, this unblocked my code. I was receiving the same error due to a similar pre-pended path as you (e.g. "c:\...\...\https:\someSite.com\someFile").

```js
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(inputStream, {
  fd: 0
});
```

Adjusting your code to this *should* work for you.

```js
request(filename).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('userInputVoice.wav', {
  fd: 0
}))
```

Hope of help!